# ERROR : Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, interface

i searched here to find solution for my error but no one match my problem , So is there anyone help me to find the error in my code !?

```
 textField_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try{
            Object selected = list_1.getSelectedValue();
                Connection conn = null;
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/flyer","root","000");
                Statement st= conn.createStatement();

                String query = "INSERT INTO flyer_item (discount) SELECT price*? FROM `item` where item_name='?' ";

                // PreparedStatement ps = null;

                int i = Integer.valueOf((textField_1.getText()));
                i=i/100;
                java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setInt(1,i);
                ps.setString(2, selected.toString());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                st.executeUpdate(query);



            } catch (SQLException se){
                System.out.println(se.getMessage());

            }

                            } } );
```

Note : mysql statement it's running successfully in workbench .
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the question mark placeholder

Change this:

```
  where item_name='?'
```

To this:

```
  where item_name= ?
```

That should resolve the problem.

With the single quotes, the prepareStatement is seeing the single quotes as enclosing a *string literal*.  The string literal happens to contain a question mark, but it's not seeing that question mark as a bind placeholder.

So the resulting prepared statement only has a single placeholder. Which is why the `setString` call is encountering an error: there is no second placeholder to supply a value for.

--

**EDIT**

Also remove this line from the code:

```
            st.executeUpdate(query);
```

And also remove this line:

```
            Statement st= conn.createStatement();
```

(The code is creating and using a prepared statement **`ps`**.)

Comment: thank you so much , i was tried that but there is error : { You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? FROM item where item_name=?' at line 1 }

Comment: Looks like that error is coming from **`st.executeUpdate(query);`** You don't want that line. Remove that. The code is using a *prepared statement* (**`ps`**). You don't need to define **`st`** at all. Remove the line **`Statement st =`** as well.

Comment: true , Thank you finally its work without any error appears ! but still the query not make anything on my table. anyway thanks a lot for your help .

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes from second parameter. within the quotes ? is treated as literal and not as a parameter.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO flyer_item (discount) SELECT price*? FROM `item` where item_name=?";
```

type conversion will autonatically handled..

Comment: thank you so much , i was tried that but there is error : { You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? FROM item where item_name=?' at line 1 }